# Commit to Assembla SVN from site5 client gives "(405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKCOL request"

Tags: svn, web-hosting

I am hosting my website on site5. Some files have changed, and I use svn to checkin those changes from my development environment and from the website. My svn server is assembla. I am trying to commit files that are on my web hosting server (site5). I have configured the server for the private key and .subversion/config tunnel section too. But I still get this error

svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKCOL request for ''

I have tried [most famous question for this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/11996/subversion-error-405-method-not-allowed-in-response-to-mkcol). This did not work for me.

Edit :

- SVN Server is assembla and the Site5 webserver is the client.
- On the site5 webserver in ~/subversion/config under [tunnel] section I have `site5 = /usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -q -l <loginid> -i <pathtoprivatekey>`
- Command I am trying `svn commit -m "message"
- Also tried `svn commit -m "message" svn+ssh://<username>/<domain>/<fullpath>`
- Both command same error

Comment: Please provide more detail about what configuration you've put in place, what you've tried, where you're trying to commit to, and what you're doing to try to commit.

Comment: added more details, hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Title of your question **unrelated to body** - you have troubles with Assembla SVN, not with site5
2. Assembla Subversion repository **never was** and **isn't** accessible with svn+ssh://, only https:// - `Source/SVN` - `Source` subtab **always** show URL of repository

**`https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/SPACENANE/`** (f repository was not renamed by hand)

Comment: Neat, why didn't I think of it. Thanks.

Comment: You can always edit a question to make it more clear. :)